# How to store (retrieve) files (txt) in elasticsearch using spring data?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am developing an application that uses elasticsearch as a database and I would like to store text files, here is my java entity.

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(indexName = "patterns")
public class Pattern {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String status;
    // How I can store this file in elasticsearch?, what type I should use for the field patternFile.
    private File patternFile; 
}
```

How can I do that using spring data elasticsearch ?.

Comment: do you want to store the filename? or the contents of the file? Why in Elasticsearch, do you need to search the document later for the data in this field?

Comment: I would only store the file contents in elasticsearch.

Comment: So you need to read the file content into a `String` and then set this as a property in your entity. Or you read as a byte[] and store it as binary content (which will be base64 encoded in Elasticsearch). If your files are small, then that's ok, if you have big files this will not be performant. But why use Elasticsearch if you are not searching on the content?

Comment: in fact i am currently migrating my database from mongodb to elasticsearch to do research on other entities.